# iOS - How to improve speed of BLE scanning in background?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, scanning, background-mode

Now I'm working on an app witch is used as "keys in phone" -- it uses bluetooth to unlock doors in seconds.

It works very well in foreground mode and I also make it work in background mode by [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1). However, when it's in background mode(especially when the screen is locked),it takes a few seconds longer to find devices than in foreground mode and at that time the device may have been asleep.

Is there any way to make it find devices as quickly as in foreground?

Comment: Do you connect to the device I order to open the door?  Do you have a pending connect?  If so then you shouldn't need to scan.

Comment: @Paulw11 THANKS AND YES, I do have a pending connect and it works fine when there is a peripheral I save as a property to be connected to. But it needs a peripheral witch has been found before I call "connectPeripheral:options:" method, isn't it? Now the problem is it cannot find peripherals quickly in background.

Comment: If it is a peripheral you have ever seen before then you can attempt to retrieve a `CBPeripheral`  using `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers` as long as you have saved the identifier somewhere (such as NSUserDefaults).  If it  is a peripheral you have never discovered then your only option is to scan.  Note that `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers` may also not return a peripheral even if it has been seen before, so you would need to fallback to a scan in that case too

Comment: @Paulw11 I really  appreciate your comment.  Do you have any way to make scan more quickly in background mode?